# python3 wikipedia parsing saving the nodes in edges file

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, html-parsing, wikipedia

So I have this python code with which I get 1000 nodes from wikipedia page, in three depths, 10 nodes from every page.

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
html = urllib2.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science').read()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

#first depth = list1
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True, title=True)[:10]:
        print(link['href'])

        #second depth = list2
        sub_html = urllib2.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org' + link['href'])
        sub_soup = BeautifulSoup(sub_html, "lxml")
        for sub_link in sub_soup.find_all('a', href=True, title=True)[:10]:
            print(sub_link['href'])

            #third depth = list3
            sub_sub_html = urllib2.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org' + link['href'])
            sub_sub_soup = BeautifulSoup(sub_sub_html, "lxml")
            for sub2_link in sub_sub_soup.find_all('a', href=True, title=True)[:10]:
                print(sub2_link['href'])
```

Next I need to save all the nodes in an edges file. I in the form:

"edge_from_list1","edge_from_list2";

"edge_from_list1","edge_from_list2";

.......

"edge_from_list2","edge_from_list3"

"edge_from_list2","edge_from_list3"

......

Can anyone give me a hint how can I do that?

Comment: Please don't put an unnecessary load on Wikipedia's servers. Learn to use the [API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are reinventing the <s>wheel</s> web-crawler here. Tools like [`Scrapy`](http://scrapy.org/) or [`PySpider`](https://github.com/binux/pyspider) would really make it much simpler and faster. Plus, the *data exporting functionality is built-in* to these tools. See the [Item Exporters](http://doc.scrapy.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/topics/exporters.html) in `Scrapy`, for example.

If you still want to stay with `BeautifulSoup` and `urllib`, you should look into [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) with [`csv.QUOTE_ALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_ALL) quoting.